# Removing the duplicate table heading when moving across pages

Tags: microsoft-word

I have copied and pasted a table into my Microsoft Word document.

If I move the table up and it moves onto the previous page, the whole table moves including the heading BUT it leaves a copy of the heading of the table on the original page. I can't remove the heading of the table left on the other page.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have (at least part of) the last row of the table on the second page?  (P.S. You should probably say what version of Word you are using.  Choosing the appropriate tag is good enough.)  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the heading row (your first one at the top of the table), and under the right-click context menu select `Table properties`. Under the `Row` tab, see if the `'Repeat as heading row'` box is selected. If you unselect that, your extra row should disappear.

Although your original description is slightly ambiguous because you say the

> ... whole table moves including the heading ...

and you do not indicate if that new location has any fresh paragraphs under the table.

Comment: That’s at best a poor workaround, and might produce issues in the future (when the table gets split over two pages again). It doesn’t address the real cause for the extra header line.